# Reusing cudaEvent to serialize multiple streams

Tags: cuda, cuda-streams, cuda-events

Suppose I have a struct:

```
typedef enum {ON_CPU,ON_GPU,ON_BOTH} memLocation;

typedef struct foo *foo;
struct foo {
  cudaEvent_t event;
  float       *deviceArray;
  float       *hostArray;
  memLocation arrayLocation;
};
```

a function:

```
void copyArrayFromCPUToGPUAsync(foo bar, cudaStream_t stream)
{
  cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream, bar->event);
  if (bar->arrayLocation == ON_CPU) {
    // ON_CPU means !ON_GPU and !ON_BOTH
    cudaMemcpyAsync(cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);
    bar->arrayLocation = ON_BOTH;
  }
  cudaEventRecord(bar->event, stream);
}

void doWorkOnGPUAsync(foo bar, cudaStream_t stream)
{
  cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream, bar->event);
  // do async work
  cudaEventRecord(bar->event, stream);
}
```

And the following scenario (with a lion, witch, and wardrobe fitting in somewhere as well):

```
// stream1, stream2, and stream3 have no prior work
// assume bar->arrayLocation = ON_GPU

doWorkOnGPUAsync(bar, stream1);
copyArrayFromCPUToGPUAsync(bar, stream2); // A no-op
doWorkOnGPUAsync(bar, stream3);
```

Is the above safe? I.e. will `stream2` still wait on `stream1` to finish its "work" if it itself does no work? And will the resulting recorded `cudaEvent` reflect this, such that `stream3` will not start until `stream1` finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be safe.

There is no mention anywhere (that I know) of some kind "event cancellation" due to lack of other work between a wait-on-event and the recording of another event. And it doesn't matter that you're re-using the same event object in the `cudaEventRecord()` call, since as the Runtime API docs [say](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EVENT.html):

> `cudaEventRecord()` can be called multiple times on the same event and will overwrite the previously captured state. Other APIs such as `cudaStreamWaitEvent()` use the most recently captured state at the time of the API call, and are not affected by later calls to `cudaEventRecord()`.

Additional notes:

- With your apparent use-case, you may also want to consider the possibility of using managed memory instead of manually copying back and forth.
- You should [check for the success](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/1593077) of your various operations, not just assume they succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! "You should check for the success of your various operations, not just assume they succeeded." Rest assured my snippets are __heavily__ pared down versions of the actual thing ;).

Comment: @JacobFaib: It doesn't have to involve longer code: Well, you wouldn't need to redact your code in this respect; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20478474/1593077) for the question I linked to.